# Error with Counterfactuals package in R - Error in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) : variable 1 has no levels

Tags: r

I am encountering errors with the counterfactuals packager in R. Any idea on how to use it? I am using it on the German Credit Risk dataset.

```r
#load the csv file as data frame
data <-  as.data.frame(read_csv('German_Credit_Data.csv'))
head(data,2)

#check for any nulls
sum(is.na(data))

#Drop Loan_ID column
data <- data[-c(1)]
head(data,2)

#check data type of the variables
str(data)

#Change all charater to factor
data=data%>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
str(data)

#split the dataset with the help of caret
split <- createDataPartition(data$Eligible, p=0.80, list=FALSE)
train <-data[split,]
test <- data[-split,]
head(test,2)

#train the model
set.seed(123)
rf <- randomForest(Eligible ~ Gender_Male+Married+Dependents+Graduate+Self_Employed+ApplicantIncome+CoapplicantIncome+
                     LoanAmount+Loan_Amount_Term+Credit_History+Property_Area, data=train, ntree=103, mtry=6, importance=TRUE)

##Model summary
rf
```

Everything is fine until here. Next, when I try to run the counterfactuals using the counterfactual package for R, I get the error:

> Error in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) : variable 1 has no levels

> In addition: Warning message: In model.response(mf,"numeric") :   using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored

```
> dput(head(data))
structure(list(Gender_Male = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male"), Married = c("No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
"Yes"), Dependents = c("0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "2"), Graduate = c("Graduate", 
"Graduate", "Graduate", "Not Graduate", "Graduate", "Graduate"
), Self_Employed = c("No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"), ApplicantIncome = c(5849, 
4583, 3000, 2583, 6000, 5417), CoapplicantIncome = c(0, 1508, 
0, 2358, 0, 4196), LoanAmount = c(128, 128, 66, 120, 141, 267
), Loan_Amount_Term = c(360, 360, 360, 360, 360, 360), Credit_History = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Property_Area = c("Urban", "Rural", "Urban", 
"Urban", "Urban", "Urban"), Eligible = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), LoanAmount_log = c(4.85203026391962, 
4.85203026391962, 4.18965474202643, 4.78749174278205, 4.94875989037817, 
5.58724865840025)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong without any data. Can you provide a small dataset that also reproduces the error? For example, the output of `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: @slamballais added above. Thanks.